# ExtJs4+: can calculated model field be editable?

Tags: extjs4, extjs5

My model has two data fields: persistent and calculated:

```
Ext.define('My.model.Value', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'percentage', type: 'float' }, // values in 0..1 range
        { name: 'percentageDecimal', type: 'float', persist: false,
            calculate: function(v) {
                v = v.percentage;
                return Ext.isNumber(v) ? v * 100.0 : v;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The `percentageDecimal` field is used in a grid and it is editable.

Question: how can I change my model to automatically update `percentage` field everytime the `percentageDecimal` is updated?

I use ExtJs 5.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used @adaskos' suggestion as follows:

```
Ext.define('My.model.Value', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'percentage', type: 'float' }, // values in 0..1 range
        { name: 'percentageDecimal', type: 'float', persist: false,
            calculate: function(v) {
                v = v.percentage;
                return Ext.isNumber(v) ? v * 100.0 : v;
            }
        }
    ],
    set: function (fieldName, value, options) {
        if (Ext.isString(fieldName)) {
            // single field update
            if (fieldName === 'percentageDecimal') {
                this.set('percentage', Ext.isNumber(value) ? 0.01 * value : value);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            // multiple fields update
            if (Ext.isDefined(fieldName.percentageDecimal)) {
                var data = Ext.clone(fieldName);
                data.percentage = Ext.isNumber(data.percentageDecimal) 
                  ? 0.01 * data.percentageDecimal 
                  : data.percentageDecimal;
                delete data.percentageDecimal;
                this.set(data);
                return;
            }
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they added an automated way to do this in 5.0.1, but you can always override the set method and whenever an update occurs to `percentageDecimal`, you recalculate the `percentage`.

An alternative I prefer: if you expect enough updates but all you want is to display it in a grid, you can remove the extra computed field from the model and set your column with `dataIndex: 'percentageDecimal'` and change its `renderer` function to display it as you like (as a decimal).

Like below:

```
... , { text: 'Percentage', dataIndex: 'percentageDecimal'
    , renderer: function (v) {
        return Ext.isNumber(v) ? v * 100.0 : v;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but I need to edit Percentage column in grid, and value to edit must be in 0..100 range.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the config options `depends` to have this updated automatically!
And use the function `convert` instead of `calculate` (not sure if it work with calculate, i need to test)

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-depends

Comment: I don't see how "depends" config can provide 2-way update. This config just tells ExtJs that 'name' field should be updated everytime the 'firstName', 'lastName' are updated.